# Jtextfield border

Tags: java, swing, border, jtextfield, keylistener

I created a formattedfield which takes only integer as input and i set its border to be a red line border if any alphabet is typed.
Now i want to set default border if user corrects the error.
how can i set default border.

Thanks For Your Help

This is my code :

```
    if(!(Character.isDigit(evt.getKeyChar()))){
        evt.consume();
        Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().beep();
        flatNoField_addUser.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.red));
    }
    else{
        ?????
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, it would look like you are using a `KeyListener` to try and filter a text field, this is a bad idea and can lead to many issues and inconsistencies.  Instead you should be using a [`DocumentFilter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/generaltext.html#filter), which is designed to do just this.

You could store a reference to the original border before your start...

```
Border border = flatNoField_addUser.getBorder();
```

And simply reapply it when you need to.

A more generic solution would be to ask the UIManger...

```
Border border = UIManager.getBorder("TextField.border");
```

The problem with this is it does not take into consideration the use case where the field had a non-default border

Answer (score 0):

You can get the original border to the `JTextField` by using by:

```
flatNoField_addUser.setBorder(UIManager.getBorder("TextField.border"));
```